# Errors when checking if HashMap key exists

Tags: java, hashmap, key

I am currently using a hashmap to store information about a Current Account.

Here is what I have in one method:

```
HashMap<String, Account> account = new HashMap<String, Account>(); 
    if (Account.validateID(accountID))  {
        System.out.println("Account ID added");
        Account a = new Account(cl,accountID, sortCode, 0);
        account.put(accountID, a); //add to HashMap     
    }
```

This seems to work fine. Then in another method I have:

```
public void enterTransaction()
{   
    String tAccountID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this,
    "Enter valid accountID", "Add Account", 0); 
    System.out.println("Check if accountID exists: " +  account.containsKey(tAccountID)); //testing if accountID exists - currently not working
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    System.out.println("Date and time of transaction: " + currentDate); //prints the date and time of transaction

}
```

Basically, i'm trying to make it so that when I go to enter a transaction, it checks that the AccountID that is entered for the transaction is equal to the AccountID from the HashMap (the key).

I tried using line 6 of the enterTransaction() to check whether it exists. However, it doesn't seem to work and always says "false" even when I know i have typed in the same accountID both times. I have also tried using this statement:

```
System.out.println(account.get(accountID));
```

This seems to give me "Account@cb1edc" ?

Sorry about the long question, it's a simple question really just thought i'd give you all the information I could. Thanks.

Comment: Could you show you `Account` class ?

Comment: Do you have `toString` method in `Account` class?

Comment: Why would it exist if you havent put it in the map yet?

Comment: Override toString() for your Account class, if the default one doesn't suffice, of course. Otherwise you are printing an Account object from the JVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct behavior. 
`account.get(accountID)` returns an Account object, which is being printed from the JVM memory dump.

To get some legible output, the Account class needs a toString method that returns a String with useful information.

When you try to print an object to the console, the JVM automatically searches for a toString method and uses that to stringify the object (make it humanly readable), if it cant find that method for the object it prints out the JVM's internal memory id for that object which looks a bit like garbage. Try this:

```
public String toString() {
    return "This is account " + this.id; // or something like this
}
```

Comment: Fast Reply! Not sure why I didn't think of using a toString. After adding to the HashMap i try doing "System.out.println(account.get(toString()));" . But now I recieve null